# Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 8

Tags: python, android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have quantized my custom trained TensorFlow model into tflite model using the following [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py) but when I put my quantized tflite model into [Tensorflow's Object detection android app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) with a label file, above mentioned error occurred in android studio. Please guide me to solve this problem. Thanks a Lot.

Custom Code used for quantization of TensorFlow model:

```sh
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/saved_model")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float16]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()

print(len(tflite_quant_model))
with open("tflite_quant_model.tflite", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_quant_model)
```

The Output which I got after adding the quantized model into [Tensorflow's Object detection android app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android):

```sh
E/TaskJniUtils: Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 8
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.initJniWithByteBuffer(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.access$100(ObjectDetector.java:88)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector$3.createHandle(ObjectDetector.java:223)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:91)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.createFromBufferAndOptions(ObjectDetector.java:219)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.<init>(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:88)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:82)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(DetectorActivity.java:105)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onPreviewFrame(CameraActivity.java:200)
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1221)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Exception!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:95)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.createFromBufferAndOptions(ObjectDetector.java:219)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.<init>(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:88)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:82)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(DetectorActivity.java:105)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onPreviewFrame(CameraActivity.java:200)
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1221)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 8
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.initJniWithByteBuffer(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.access$100(ObjectDetector.java:88)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector$3.createHandle(ObjectDetector.java:223)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:91)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.createFromBufferAndOptions(ObjectDetector.java:219) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.<init>(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:88) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:82) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(DetectorActivity.java:105) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onPreviewFrame(CameraActivity.java:200) 
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1221) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Same Issue on [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/55664).